# Rebuilding Windows Server 2003 after Motherboard failure - can't Activate or get to MS Update

Tags: motherboard, windows-activation, windows-server-2003

I recently had a motherboard failure on my Windows Server 2003 box.  I have now installed a different motherboard and reinstalled 2003 from the original disks and install key.  All of that went fine, but apparently the install disks did not have a driver for the on-board Ethernet hardware. After some web searching I found a driver that works and allows me to get to the internet with the IE browser.

At that point I tried to Activate the OS and that failed with a message that it could not access the Activation Server, "Check your Internet connection?!!  I get basically the same error when I try to access Windows (or Microsoft) Update.

As I know the Internet connection is working, I have even installed Symantec's SEP which did the full "Live Update".

I'm stumped.  Can you help?.....RDK

Comment: Activate by phone?